# Analyzing query string in sammy.js?

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I'm using sammy.js , I already know how to "cut"  this url into parts:

`<a href="#/label/drafts">drafts</a>`

via

```
  this.get('#/label/:name', function(context) {

              context.$element().append('<h1>' + this.params['name'] + '</h1>'); 
          });
```

But how can I cut this complext url ?

```
<a href="#/label/drafts?a=1&b=2&c=love#a">How to solve this ? </a>
```

Question :

How can I extract (sammy's way ):

- `a` 's value   (expected `1`)
- `b` 's value (expected `2`)
- `c` 's value ( without hash) (expected `love`)
- `c` 's hash (expected `a`)

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/hohip/1/edit)

*n.b. Im looking for the sammy'js way ( I obviously can cut it via pure javascript , but again , I want the sammy'js way  - if possible)*

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but most probably this is impossible. The last time I was reading documentation, I was not able to find anything about this.

Comment: @SalvadorDali tnx.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Sammy.js does support query parameters, so you would be able to use most of your current example in your URL (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853196/sammy-js-read-route-with) for an example). What it doesn't support is `#` in your URL, out of necessity. It defines a query string as a `?` followed by any number of non-hash characters (including none). This is due to the fact that a url like `/index?param=foo#bar` is a valid URL which is (according to the HTTP standard) split up like so:

- route is '/index'
- query parameter 'param' is set to 'foo'
- location.hash is set to 'bar'

If Sammy were to include a hash character within the set of valid query parameter characters, then it wouldn't be able to recognize a hash easily on valid URLs. However, if you were to URL encode the hash, you'd be able to utilize it within your route.

So, in conclusion, Sammy can get you close to what you want, but it can't get you all the way there due to how it defines query parameters.

Comment: @can you please edit my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hohip/1/edit) to get the QS values ? you answer there doesn't have a code so other can use. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Yes you right I got it [here](http://jsbin.com/hohip/5/edit). the last `#` mess it all

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing how i solved the issue for myself so that it can help others.

```
<a href="/#/Listing/Index/4?listtypeid=SomeId" class="list-group-item">@item.Name</a>
```

In Sammy

```
   this.get('/#/Listing/Index/:id', function (context) {
       context.app.swap('');
       context.$element().append('<h1>Here are parameters id: ' + this.params['id'] + ' and listingtypeid: ' + this.params['listtypeid'] + '</h1>');
       // OR
       //context.$element().append('<h1>Here are parameters id: ' + this.params.id + ' and listingtypeid: ' + this.params.listtypeid + '</h1>');

   });
```

In case some time listingtypeid could be null or not present you should first check parameter in your code.